How to diagnose slow ssh with OpenStack floating IP
I run VPS instances created with OpenStack hosted by a major provider. When I ssh from machine1 in the LAN to a machine2 or local IP address, the connection is immediate and always fast. With ssh from machine1 to machine2.domain.tld the "password" prompt is immediate but the time from there to shell can be very long. Sometimes the same pattern occurs across the internet from my Windows desktop to the FQDN. ("Sometimes" indicating the issue is not a clear break but inconsistent.)
These instances are using floating IPs and my DNS provides A records (not yet AAAA) records for the FQDNs.
This is not unique to a single installation. I have reinstalled new client and server Ubuntu instances from vendor-provided images and I always have the same results. The instances being tested do not have any stack installed yet. I have recreated DNS records and rechecked /etc/hosts and other settings in every installation. I want to get through this issue before installing LAMP, Node, or other packages.
I have not been successful in diagnosing the delays. This very specific area is not in my skillset. I'm hoping for some guidance to trace what is happening, for myself and anyone else with this challenge.
The delay does not seem to come from server scripts like .bashrc or .profile. I'm adding timing logs now to check this all the way through PAM, profiles, motd's, etc.
I've tried strace and tcpdump and other commands (omitting rigorous details here) but when there is a pause the problem is still not obvious. It's like both sides are just waiting for packets. The client sends a keepalive ping, the server may respond, but the client doesn't get the keepalive responses and may eventually close. It does seem like packets are just not getting back to the client.
Ideas so far:

I'm told OpenStack floating IPs are notoriously slow when used like this because of the need to modify every packet. Does anyone have links or doc references for this?
A difference in MTU size that forces packet restructuring somewhere along the way?
I'm new to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, maybe there's something I need to do with netplan to change the server config, or in resolv.conf?
Maybe the server is missing some package that is designed to help with this? I always need to manually add net-tools.
UFW is installed and active, OpenSSH is the only profile, allowing 22/tcp access.
Maybe I need to do something with IPv6 now for SSH or with AAAA record in DNS? (There is a PTR record and an A record for the FQDN.)
Local IP address of client getting presented to server, so returned packets on the external interface never get back to the client? (Except that after a long delay everything does come back)
File lock somewhere during pubkey authentication, check on known_hosts, etc?
A delay as some PAM, profile, or MOTD script connects to a remote site. SSHD trace has shown login was successful but the client doesn't get the response. So this would need to be somewhere in the PAM process before profile scripts. I have added output lines at the top of profile scripts but don't see that output in the client, so the issue must be (?) before profile and MOTD.
Maybe I'm missing something in the floating IP configuration, a PTR record (there is one)

If this inquiry doesn't conform to StackExchange/Server Fault guidelines, I'll be happy to revise. I'm trying to understand how to solve the problem. The answer would ultimately be a step by step "try this, then try this ...". I'm hoping interactions here will lead to a successful process that someone can then revise into a single Answer.
Please hold back criticisms of incompetence - I'm a competent developer and I hope I've shown I can survive at this level, but I am not a professional DevOps guy and this is not my full-time occupation.
